# Regex match first numbers and allow only 11

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex that verifies first 6 numbers of 11 are in this date format 'yymmdd' and verifies it only contains 11 numbers.

Example: 06060612345

```
^((0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|31(?!(?:0[2469]|11))|30(?!02))(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0?[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]))
```

Comment: Remember, a regex will only validate _the format_, not if it's a valid date or not. 200231 is not a valid date, but it is in the correct format.

Comment: If you want to actually validate the date (and the format at the same time) consider using the widely used MomentJS.

Comment: You can pass it through the regex pattern matches only if it has 11 digits.

Comment: As has been pointed out, the "correct format" could lead to invalid dates. I would suggest just checking for 11 digits, and separately checking if the first 6 make a valid date.

Comment: First verify if the input is all digits with `^[0-9]{1}$` and then use `.substring()` to feed the first 6 into `moment()` like this `moment(input.substring(0, 6), 'YYMMDD')` and check if it succeeded. See https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/known-formats/

Comment: It is not generally a good idea to validate dates using regex. If you're tempted to try, remember that `120229` is valid but `110229` is not. Do basic verification if you like - ie that it consists of digits - but actual date verification should be done by a date/time libary.

Comment: You are attempting to determine if a string could represent a date. It’s hard to imagine that being useful. If it could be a date won’t you then have to determine if it is one, using methods that tell you that, for example, that `000229` is a valid date? If so, why not just skip the regex? You present a regex without telling us if it works, and if it fails, why it fails. That regex does not require the entire string to contain 11 characters. Should it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments using regex for validation doesn't realy work. Make it easier on yourself, by using a regex like `const match = "06060612345".match(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{5})$/)`. Then using `Date.parse`:

```js
// Generates our yyyy/mm/dd date string for our argument.
const date = [20 + match[1], match[2], match[3]].join('/'); 

// And to check validity you can use this instead of the
// massive moment js lib as suggested in the comments.
const isValid = !isNaN(Date.parse(date));
```

And if needed the extra numbers are in `match[4]`.

Comment: Thank you ! I wasn't expecting that kind of solution, I will try.

Answer (score 1):

This:

`^((0[1-9])|([1-9]{2}))((0[1-9]|1[0-2]))(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|(?<!(?:(0[2469])|11))31|(?<!02)30)\d{5}$`

is close to what you're looking for. The format should be fine but it also accepts some invalid dates like `192901`

This is also the reason why you want to avoid using regex for such tasks. If you're using it for anything remotely complex. Assuming your regex supports recursion you could use some [modulo tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42193223/modulo-operator-in-a-regular-expression) to check for leap years, but again I really **really** would advise you against it unless there is a specific reason or it serves a recreational purpose (e.g. some kind of programming challenge)